# Difference between UiSelector text and textContains

Tags: android, python, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I was referring some code to click on the button. I found two following ways to do it but, I didn't understand the difference between them

```
from uiautomator import device as dev
dev(text="OK").click()
```

and another was

```
dev(textContains="OK").click()
```

what is the difference between them?
I referred the documentation for [text](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector.html#text) and [textContains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector.html#textcontains) but I still didn't get the difference between these two methods.

Also, after the click operation how do we find out whether the action of click was performed or not?

Answer (score 0):

The `text` method will find match exactly a string. However, `textContains` will find a string with wildcard character. Example:

With string: "Ok is a string"

`dev(text="OK").click()` will fail and cannot click.
`dev(textContains="OK").click()` will pass and click.

Comment: Yes, I understood. Also, about my second question how do we get to know whether the click operation was performed successfully or not? I checked for the return type of the click method but I didn't find out.